Oracle PL/SQL setting spool commands. I need to clear output from variable values
I have a test table "bbb".



COLB




bba


aa1


bbb


aaa


bbb


bb1



and do following commands:

variable a varchar2(20);
begin
    :a:='bbb';
end;
/
set heading off;
spool C:\Temp\test.txt;
set feedback off;

select * from bbb t where t.colb=:a;

spool off;

But I see in test.txt following:
bbb
bbb
a
---------
bbb

How can I rid of information?:
a
---------
bbb

I need only info of result in file:
bbb
bbb

I tried to execute.
SET VERIFY OFF:
SET ECHO OFF;
But it does not help me.

You can try using SET PAGESIZE 0

Seems like you might have AUTOPRINT set to ON; try SET AUTOPRINT OFF

@Boneist, you are right! Thanks a lot!!!
